# Controller logic for multiple filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following methods defined in my `tutor.rb` model

```
def self.fees_search(n)
    @profile = Profile.fees_to(n)
    if @profile.empty?
      return Tutor.none
    else
      @profile.map do |y|
        y.tutor
      end
    end
  end

  def self.subject_search(s)
    @subject = Subject.find_by_name(s)
    unless @subject.nil?
      @subject.tutors 
    end
  end
```

And in my `tutors_controller.rb` i have the following for

```
def index
    @tutor = Tutor.all
    @tutor = @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search]) if params[:fees_search].present?
    @tutor = @tutor.subject_search(params[:subject_search]) if params[:subject_search].present?
  end
```

The searches both work when applied independently, but when i try to do both, i get the error `undefined method`subject_search' for #`now i suppose its because the first method of`fees_search` would be processed first? Thats why i think i'm getting this error. How should i code my controller action differently then? To accept both filters?

Greatly appreciate all advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the condtions of what params are `present`,

```
def index
    @tutor = Tutor.all

    @tutor_array = []

    @tutor_array << @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search]) if (params[:fees_search].present?

    @tutor_array << @tutor.subject_search(params[:subject_search]) if (params[:subject_search].present?

    @tutor_array << @tutor.location_search(params[:location_search]) if (params[:location_search].present?

   @tutor_array.each do |tutor| 
     ids = @tutor.merge(tutor).map(&:id) 
     @tutor = Tutor.where(id: ids) 
   end

end
```

[Here is the reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

Comment: I'll try that out, but what if i had a 3rd or even 4th search parameter? Say if i did `@tutor = @tutor.location_search` etc. How do i further extend that logic? Because if there were 3 filters and not 2, i could choose to apply either 2 or 3 filters simultaneously, and that seems like its gonna bloat up the code due to increase in combination?

Comment: is that the same way you will send the params? will you call the method based on the params?, when you need the multiple filters to apply?

Comment: im really sorry but i don't quite understand what you mean... do you think you could elaborate?

Comment: when you exactly need the multiple filters to get applied?

Comment: There isn't exactly a when. It comes from user input through a form. Which is why at times there may only be 1 filter applied, at times there may be 3 or 4 filters applied. Right now i'm stuck at getting 2 to work simultaneously

Comment: I changed my answer please check now.

Comment: `undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0x007fc26a2a5380>` That's the error i'm getting. With the line `@tutor = @tutor.merge(tutor)` highlighted. I'll read up on `.merge` though

Comment: merge returns an array, try to convert it into active record, `Tutor.where(id: ( @tutor.merge(tutor).map(&:id) ))`

Comment: Sorry but do i replace `@tutor = @tutor.merge(tutor)` with the line you provided?

Comment: filter doesnt even work with that line. should it be `@tutor.where`? Since without the `@tutor`, my index is rendering off the `@tutor` instance variable anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125070/discussion-between-sravan-and-angkiki).